How can I replace my REMOTE .git folder and its contents FROM my LOCAL repo, NOT copying/recreating the entire repo
I have had to recreate my remote repo by uploading a copy of my local .gitignore, then pushing all data files/folders, but cannot find any way to upload ONLY the "hidden" .git folder to my remote. All answers I have found only describe the REVERSE direction (remote to local). I have un-hidden the local .git folder. I cannot use the default VS .gitignore as it does not ignore ALL the VS files.
I tried "git push .git", but it says "everything up to date. However, when I check my remote branches, only "main" exists.
This post is different from previous posts, because they all cause git to upload the VS files along with my files, forcing me to move to LFS. Those methods, for some reason, bypass the .gitignore file, which I have set to explicitly ignore those large files, especially since they have nothing to do with my code. My .gitignore also says to ignore the pch.h and pch.cpp files, which also get uploaded.

The hidden .git folder is the repo.

git push .git doesn't make sense. That would be putting your repo in your repo ... just a mess.

"This post is different from previous posts, because they all cause git to upload the VS files along with my files"—you're fundamentally misunderstanding how Git works. If "the VS files" are being uploaded, that means they've been committed and they're part of your repository. If you don't want them to be part of the repository, don't commit them. As evolutionbox and topsail already said, git push .git is nonsensical.

Yes, I understand my error in thinking I could upload the .git folder (with my commit info) that way. I have since learned to use  "git rm -cached r .vs" to undo what vs did in creating the repo. But I still do not see how to "copy" my local commits to the remote to get the "instructions" for my second branch included in the remote.

@DocDJ, what do you mean by '"copy my local commits to the remote'? Git doesn't "copy", but it does push. I'm not sure what you mean by '"instructions" for my second branch' ("instruction" isn't a Git term), but the linked duplicates show you how to push all of your local commits, across all local branches, to the remote.

By "copy", I mean: to create a duplicate of the commit operations (instructions) of my local repo onto my remote, so they are synchronized in content, commits and branching. I DID get git to "push --follow-tags" but the remote still does not show the same branches as the local (the local has only "main" and a 2nd called "doit". I deleted the remote VS files and committed the deletion, so the file content is as it should be if .gitignore worked. I am also getting "changes not staged for commit "modified: .gitignore" which has the additions to ignore the additional VS files.

Commits aren't operations. A commit is a snapshot of all files in the repo.

@evolutinxbox: "Snapshot" thanks for that clarification. So if I understand, the commits tell git how to reproduce the sequence of changes I made in my local repo to obtain the same results (changes and branches) on my remote. And THAT does not seem to be happening, because I clearly still do not have the proper command sequence to reproduce my local repo WITHOUT relying on the .gitignore file to prevent copying the VS files. Or is there a way to get VS to put ITS files somewhere outside my repo? Or getting my remote to be in sync with my local if I manually remove those files from the remote.

"the commits tell git how to reproduce the sequence of changes I made in my local repo" - no a single commit is the current state of the repo at the time of committing. It's not a diff or set of instructions.

Understood. So I created an empty remote with  VS .gitignore. But. It does not ignore ALL the local VS files, thus overflowing my basic storage. So I edited and committed the remote .gitignore to match my local. Now I need to get the correct files and my 2 branches created on the remote. But my remote and local are un-synced, because the remote "has no common commits". So git refuses to push --all.  SO how do I get that one commit onto my local?

How did you create the empty remote?

@Chris As a new user to git with VS, I (incorrectly) assumed that the default VS .gitiognore provided when I created my local repo, was complete. I merrily went on with building and committing my code. Now I am out of remote storage, because some of the VS files are too big.

@evolutionbox I created the empty remote with Github (because I thought a UI would be easier for a beginner than CLI.)

@DocDJ no worries. I was just making sure that you hadn't done it manually.

I have reported the default .gitignore file for VS repos as a bug in github.

@DocDJ why did you do that? What do you see as being a bug? Had you committed the files before adding the .gitignore?

FIRST: I started from a bare repo requesting the default VS .ignore file, hoping my huge VS-related files would not be added when I did a push. Git still tried to load those files, but it DID ignore the files in the default .gitignore. 2nd: new bare repo. No .gitignore. Did a push --all and git ignored my LOCAL .gitignore, so it tried to upload all those VS files. I need a .gitignore that is up to date viz-a-vie VS 2019+

@evolutionxbox Thee github-provided VS .gitignore file is missing the following:
*.vcxproj
*.filters
.aps
res/
x64/
Debug/
M_exifie./                      // this name is composed of the 1st 8 chars of the repo name
pch.h
pch.cpp
The directories are very large.

It's really hard to see in the comments. Please add the gitignore that didn't work, and some example names of files which were added

@evolutionxbox stack overflow doesn't allow uploading of files, but I have copied my modified one (with the relevant new ignores) onto my public website link. Look for the file named my.gitignore near the bottom of the folder/file list.

Just fir grins, I deleted & recreated my bare git remote repo, then opened VS to my project. went to git>push and it obeyed my .local gitignore, BUT when I went to git>manage branches, it in the tree, it shows reponame>main and a 2nd entry labeled remotes/origin, which when clicked shows all my branches (main & split_doit_thread doit). in github, the 2nd branch does not show. I seem to be faced with closing both repos (thus merging my branches, then rebuilding both local and remote repos. PS. git development has accepted my bug report as a problem, but no guarantee of when it will get fixed.

@DocDJ may you share that bug report?

[link(https://support.github.com/ticket/2966892)  We appreciate you taking the time to write in with this feedback around our .gitignore templates. I can't promise when/if we will be able to make any changes to that feature but I would be happy to mark your report internally as feedback for the team to review and consider.

Somehow, in the process of solving my problems, I've lost my branches. git status doesn’t show them, but the VS git management screen still refers to those branches as if they are on my remote repo (but lost in my local). VS git push applies most .gitignore rules, so re-creating the remote repo as a single branch results. I’ve spent 3 weeks trying git commands to fully obey the .gitignore file w/o success. I am going to completely delete everything git local and remote and restart from what is the end of my latest branch. Thanks to all who have offered help. Frustrated, but not defeated.

"VS git push applies most .gitignore rules" what does this mean? git push is not affected by the gitignore file. I think you might be confusing things. If a file has already been committed it won't be ignored.

@evolutionbox So it seems to be that using git push form inside VS, my ignores or (having turned off tracking on those files in the past) I only get the files I want. BUT if I do a git push from the cli, then nothing gets ignored (git continues to complain about the VS files that are too big and I need to use LFS, which got me to this sad state in the first place (because the default LFS size wasn't big enough for these "bad" files). I didn't want them there anyway, so tried to stop them.  Yes, my understanding of git is minimal, but I was doing fine until I ran out of space. Github no help.

@evolutionbox PS. If github had let me use my own .gitignore file I might have realized it wasn't getting used and I'd have searched for more info on commits, tracking, caching and push. What VS did under the covers was also hiding what I had wrong. Luckily, my 2nd branch (and the code in my repo) are all I need to continue working. I won't need to fallback to main. The 1st things I didn't get when starting CLI are 1: what origin and main mean and 2: the use of main vs master with git and github. Many thanks for your time & help. I'll try to get better educated.

"If github had let me use my own .gitignore" - they do. I'm baffled why you think they don't?

@evolutionbox When I create a NEW repo, there are several choices available for pre-defined .gitignore files. There is no option for uploading my own. Modifying the pre-defined VS file, requires a commit and that puts my bare repo out of sync with my local repo. AND I don't want to do a pull, because (it appears to me from the description of pull, that) it will delete all my local files to put the local in sync with the remote. All the examples I have found seem to treat the remote as the "master" and the local as a sub-ordinate copy. PS. Why have .gitignore if it isn't used by commit/push?
